# Помогите вывести данные в html из json

Tags: html, json, html5

Есть API на стороннем сервисе, нужно вывести json данные в читаемом формате с разделителями
https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?total=1&json=true

Заранее спасибо!

Пробовал разные методы

пока остановился на

```html
<body>
<div id="body"></div>

<script>
(function() {
 var eobotAPI = "http://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?total=245787&json=true";
 $.getJSON( eobotAPI, {
   tags: "Total,BTC,ETH,LTC,STEEM,DOGE,XRP,DASH,GNT,BTS,CURE,XEM,XMR,ZEC,FCT,BCN,REP,LSK,MAID,USD,GRC,GOLD,GHS,GHS2,SCRYPT,BPPD,PPD",
   tagmode: "any",
   format: "json"
 });

$.getJSON( eobotAPI, { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $('body').append($('<div>', {
            text: element.Total
        }));
    });
});  

});

</script>

</body>
```

Но все-равно не работает, не получается вывести элементы с запроса в html (в тело страницы) подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно куда вывести данные и что такое читаемый формат. Возможно вам поможет тег <pre>

Comment: Можно подробнее про тег <pre>?

Comment: Тег <pre> не подойдет для данной задумки
нужно вывести из json данные в html

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin Обновил информацию

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел очень простейший пример, он и сработал

```html
<?php
$json_string = 'http://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?total=245787&json=true';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($obj);

//echo "<br>";
//print_r($obj["Total"]);"<br>";
?>

<html>

<div>
<p>Всего добыто в рублях <?=$obj["Total"];?></p>
<p>BTC <?=$obj["BTC"];?></p>
<p>ETH <?=$obj["ETH"];?></p>
<p>LTC <?=$obj["LTC"];?></p>
<p>STEEM <?=$obj["STEEM"];?></p>
<p>DOGE <?=$obj["DOGE"];?></p>
<p>XRP <?=$obj["XRP"];?></p>
<p>DASH <?=$obj["DASH"];?></p>
<p>GNT <?=$obj["GNT"];?></p>
<p>BTS <?=$obj["BTS"];?></p>
<p>CURE <?=$obj["CURE"];?></p>
<p>XEM <?=$obj["XEM"];?></p>
<p>XMR <?=$obj["XMR"];?></p>
<p>ZEC <?=$obj["ZEC"];?></p>
<p>FCT <?=$obj["FCT"];?></p>
<p>BCN <?=$obj["BCN"];?></p>
<p>REP <?=$obj["REP"];?></p>
<p>LSK <?=$obj["LSK"];?></p>
<p>MAID <?=$obj["MAID"];?></p>
<p>USD <?=$obj["USD"];?></p>
<p>GRC <?=$obj["GRC"];?></p>
<p>GOLD <?=$obj["GOLD"];?></p>
<p>GHS 3 <?=$obj["GHS"];?></p>
<p>GHS 4 <?=$obj["GHS2"];?></p>
<p>SCRYPT <?=$obj["SCRYPT"];?></p>
<p>BPPD <?=$obj["BPPD"];?></p>
<p>PPD <?=$obj["PPD"];?></p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Обновить страницу" onClick="window.location.reload()">

</html>
```

-->

```
<html>

<div>
<p>Всего добыто в рублях <?=$obj["Total"];?></p>
<p>BTC <?=$obj["BTC"];?></p>
<p>ETH <?=$obj["ETH"];?></p>
<p>LTC <?=$obj["LTC"];?></p>
<p>STEEM <?=$obj["STEEM"];?></p>
<p>DOGE <?=$obj["DOGE"];?></p>
<p>XRP <?=$obj["XRP"];?></p>
<p>DASH <?=$obj["DASH"];?></p>
<p>GNT <?=$obj["GNT"];?></p>
<p>BTS <?=$obj["BTS"];?></p>
<p>CURE <?=$obj["CURE"];?></p>
<p>XEM <?=$obj["XEM"];?></p>
<p>XMR <?=$obj["XMR"];?></p>
<p>ZEC <?=$obj["ZEC"];?></p>
<p>FCT <?=$obj["FCT"];?></p>
<p>BCN <?=$obj["BCN"];?></p>
<p>REP <?=$obj["REP"];?></p>
<p>LSK <?=$obj["LSK"];?></p>
<p>MAID <?=$obj["MAID"];?></p>
<p>USD <?=$obj["USD"];?></p>
<p>GRC <?=$obj["GRC"];?></p>
<p>GOLD <?=$obj["GOLD"];?></p>
<p>GHS 3 <?=$obj["GHS"];?></p>
<p>GHS 4 <?=$obj["GHS2"];?></p>
<p>SCRYPT <?=$obj["SCRYPT"];?></p>
<p>BPPD <?=$obj["BPPD"];?></p>
<p>PPD <?=$obj["PPD"];?></p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Обновить страницу" onClick="window.location.reload()">

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.json')
const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
const url = 'https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?total=245787&json=true'

 async function getJson() {
   try {
       const response = await fetch(proxy+url)
       await response.json().then(response => {
           for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(response)) {
              const inHtml = `<div>${key}: ${val}</div>`
               container.innerHTML += inHtml
           }
       })
   } catch (e) {
       console.log(e.message)
   }
}
getJson()
```

```html
<div class="json"></div>
```

не повторяй моего извращение - получи нормально данные через пыхыпы )